# Tired and sick feeling fixed by eating

Tags: meat

I, despite eating normally and drinking normally, on very rare occasion seem to hit a wall or something. I get really tired and start yawning very regularly and usually also start feeling light headed and sick.

Despite not feeling hungry it usually goes away if I eat some meat. I don't know what it is but it has happened twice in the last month. Does anyone know what could cause something like this?

Edit --

Mostly each day I eat as follows or a slight variation.

Breakfast : Couple of small bits of bacon, fried egg, toast, glass of water and a coffee

Morning snack : Usually a flavored tuna snack and water and coffee

Lunch : Salad with dressing or a Soup

Afternoon snack : Biscuits and coffee

Dinner : variety of typical dinner options (steak & veggies, pasta, casserole, etc)

I am also walking/jogging about 3.5kms in a little over half an hour in the mornings before breakfast 3-4 times a week.

As for specific details about what I ate/drank when it happened I don't remember but will try to keep track so I will know if it happens again.

Comment: Sometimes you can become nauseous from being so hungry. What exactly are you eating?

Comment: Have edited the question to include more details about meals.

Answer (score 1):

This was happening to me, seems I was losing a lot of basic nutrients/vitamins when working out (sweated them out) - I started to take my whey protein prior to the workout and drank vita-water (added the powder to my water) during the workout and I stopped hitting the mid morning wall.  Sounds like your lacking/need to increase something (protein or vitamins).  More info is required, like what you were doing on those days, your workout, your meals.....and if there were any specific differences on those days.

Comment: Agree. The fact that eating meat seems to keep the feeling at bay seems to indicate a deficiency, most likely protein. Try experimenting with other foods to see if it helps too: protein shakes, salads, soups.

Comment: Have edited the question to include more details about meals.

Answer (score 0):

Biscuits are generally high in sugar and starch, neither of which will give you energy to sustain you for more than a short time. You're better having foods containing good fats, protein, and fibre. Those foods also give you a feeling of fullness, which means you don't need to eat as much as you would with biscuits.

Salads can be quite light sometimes, so if the soup doesn't have much substance to it, that won't give you much to go on either. You might need something more substantial such as some whole-grain bread (dip it in your soup?) to last you through to dinnertime, especially if you're having biscuits in the afternoon.